# Submit a Form Using jQuery Post Method and Stay on the Same Page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm trying to improve the usability of my form by not having it reload when it is submitted. In the case below, I want to call index.php when the submit button named "delete-image" is clicked. Please note, there are two buttons in the form, so the jQuery should check on type="submit" with name "delete-image" being clicked instead of just triggering when the form is submitted. Also, when "delete-image" is pressed, the jQuery should change the img's source to "deleted.jpg."

I have heard that jQuery's .post() is the best way to handle this, but remember, the key is to not reload the page.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="edit">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="">
    <input type="submit" name="delete-image" value="Delete Image"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Any suggestions are welcomed please.

Comment: `$('form').on('submit',function(e){ ... $.ajax(); OR $.post(); e.preventDefault(); //prevents reloading the page}`

Comment: Sean: I'm trying to make it not on submit, but rather when the "delete-image" button is clicked.

Comment: When a `<input type="submit">` button is clicked inside a form, by default it will submit the form. Using the binding I suggested, when `name="delete-image"` is clicked the form will submit, but using `e.preventDefault();` it will prevent it from submitting.

Comment: I don't get it. How to you bind it to the name="delete-image" button?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer.  What you are looking for is a an asynchronous post using ajax.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

Comment: why are you linking to w3schools and not the actual docs - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/?

Comment: @sean Good call on including that as well, but as he is new to ajax, I thought I would send over a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `$.post` method.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post

Here's an example:

```
$.post("url", data, function(data){
  // stuff to do when done
});
```

In your case:

```
$("input[name='delete-image']").click(function(e){

   // Prevent default form submission
   e.preventDefault();

   // Perform AJAX request
   $.post("index.php", data, function(data){

      // if you plan to change the image source
      // when you've received the response
      $("img").attr("src", "deleted.jpg");
   });
});
```

Here's the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/domingokyle/EVkP6/1/

To prevent form submission, you can use jQuery's `submit()` method

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  return false;
});
```

Or change the button type to "button".

Comment: Kyle, this looks like what I'm looking for. However, it reloads the page. Is there a way we can tweak it so it calls index.php (which handles my DB query) without reloading?

Comment: Which button is used for sending the request? the delete-image button? or the go button?. 

The example I gave you finds the button with the name of "delete-image", gives it a click handler, prevents the default action of the submit button, and sends a post request to index.php

Comment: Kyle: I re-tried your code on my script and it still reloads the page. In fact, even in your jsfiddle, if you click on the Delete Image button, it reloads the page. Maybe if we set the URL to the form's action value instead of index.php?

Comment: Try to check my fiddle again. i've updated it. it wasn't using the jQuery library before.